# Multi-threaded merge sort for performance measurement

Tags: c, multithreading, mergesort

I am trying to compare the performance difference in merge sort using a single threaded and multi-threaded program. The time taken to sort an array of size ~ 50000 using a single thread took 0.01x seconds, whereas for an array of same size, using 2/4/8 threads took 0.02-0.03 seconds. I know, the difference is not much, but I'm just curious to know what could be the reason for the slowdown in multi-threaded program?
Below is the code for single-threaded program (main function's code):

```
 srand(clock());            //to seed-random numbers
 readData(A,n);
 clock_t start=clock();
 mergeSort(A,0,n-1);
 clock_t end=clock();
```

And, for the multi-threaded program :

```
int n=50000;        //n is the size
int no_of_threads=4;
limit S;              //structure containing array,start and end index
srand(clock());         //to seed-random numbers
generateData(&S,n);
pthread_t id[no_of_threads];
int i=0,size=0,k=n/no_of_threads;
clock_t start=clock();
for(i=0; i<no_of_threads; i++)
{
        S.start=size,S.end=size+k-1;
        pthread_create(&id[i],NULL, sorter ,&S);
        size=size + k;
}
for(i=0; i<no_of_threads; i++)
        pthread_join(id[i],NULL);
mergeSort(S.A,0,n-1);
clock_t end=clock();
```

Sorter function:

```
void* sorter(void *s)
{
    limit *S=(limit*)s;
    int start=S->start,end=S->end;
    mergeSort(S->A,start,end);
}
```

Comment: Threading adds overhead. It's **only** beneficial when you manage to perform *enough* operations in parallel to balance this overhead.

Comment: You're doing a lot more work in the threaded version with thread creation and so on. You're also starting the threads wrong; you don't ensure that each thread has its own data structure passed to it so they may be duplicating work (and leaving work undue).  You also spear to do the sort again after the threads finish, AFAICS.

Comment: Undefined behavior for non-readonly, non-atomic, unsynchronized access to a shared object from multiple threads.

Comment: I do understand that, but for an array of size ~50000, multi-threaded program should've improved the performance. And, regarding the access from multiple threads, I have taken care of the same using semaphores. Still, the performance issue exists... :(

Comment: @KunalAgarwal: I don't see a single semaphore in your code. Hence, your code is completely wrong, and the performance is the *least* of your problems.

Comment: @EOF: Well, to make it short, I had removed those lines before posting here. Since, the prime concern was only performance.
Full code:
       clock_t start=clock();  
 for(i=0; i<no_of_threads; i++)
 {
   sem_wait(&sem);
   S.start=size,S.end=size+k-1;
   pthread_create(&id[i],NULL, sorter ,&S);
   size=size + k;
 }
 for(i=0; i<no_of_threads; i++)
   pthread_join(id[i],NULL);
 clock_t end=clock();

Sorter function():
      int start=S->start,end=S->end;
 sem_post(&sem);
 mergeSort(S->A,start,end);

Comment: @KunalAgarwal: As best as I can tell from this unformatted fragment, you were also not using the semaphore correctly. Of course it is somewhat difficult to tell without an MCVE, which is why I voted to close this question until you provide one.

Comment: It seems like threading would work for things like mergesort or timsort where different parts of the overall sequence need to be massaged anyway.  Define a task, set limits on what data it can touch, kick off a thread.  Task is done, thread sets a semaphore and closes.  Maybe more overhead than it's worth, or keep the threads open and assign them tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dividing the work, you are doing extra work. In each thread, when the number of threads is `x`, you are sorting `1/x` of the array. 
After all the threads have completed, you are again calling merge sort on the whole array, which will recursively partition the array right till the bottom and merge, ignoring the fact that sub parts are already sorted.

One way you could use to overcome this is, instead of calling the `mergeSort()` function again, you simply merge the sorted subparts, which can be done in `O(nx)` time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got the error, but even after removing the mergeSort() function, time difference still exists, what could be the reason? Still, the single-threaded program is running faster, which shouldn't be the case, I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a common structure for S, it is possible that S is getting updated in parallel with the thread creation? Perhaps make S an array of no_of_threads structs,  then use S[i] for each create thread.

```
#define no_of_threads 4
limit S[no_of_threads];
// ...
    for(i=0; i<no_of_threads; i++)
    {
        S[i].start=size,S[i].end=size+k-1;
        pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, sorter, &S[i]);
        size=size + k;
    }
// ...   after the joins, do a k-way merge (not a merge sort).
```

I did this a while back using a bottom up merge sort, and your example with top down merge sort uses the same idea. For k threads, split the array into k parts (in my simple example I assume array size is a multiple of k), then merge sort the k parts in parallel, so far this is the same as your code (except for the common S structure). My version then merges pairs of runs of size k using k/2 threads, each doing a 2 way merge, then merges pairs of runs of size 2k using k/4 threads, again each doing a 2 way merge, ... . Before I tested this, I expected little gain because I though the tight loop (compare two elements, move the smaller) in the merge part would be memory bandwidth limited, but it turns out that loop is cpu limited. On an Intel 3770k 3.5ghz with 4 cores, for k = 4, the merge sort was 3 times as fast as single threaded merge sort, and for k = 8, the merge sort was about 3.9 times as fast. Most of the speed up is due to the local L1 and L2 caches in each core. Link to my prior thread about this, and although it's a Windows example with separate main thread functions, consider it as a proof of concept that multi-threading merge sort is faster than single threaded merge sort.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025/multithreaded-bottom-up-merge-sort

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have created different structure variables for each thread, and even commented out the last k-way merge portion. But even without performing the merge operation (in multi-threaded program), it seems to run a bit slower than the normal one. What could be the reason? In my case, single-threaded merge sort is proving out to be a bit faster, which shouldn't be the case, I suppose? Or am I missing out something?

Comment: @KunalAgarwal - what kind of times are you getting? On my system (Intel 3770k 3.5 ghz), sorting 16 million 32 bit integers took a bit less than 0.5 seconds with 4 thread merge sort and a bit less than 1.5 seconds with single thread merge sort.

Comment: Yup, I checked, whether the data is being sorted or not. It is getting sorted as well. Don't know, what could be the reason. :(

Comment: @KunalAgarwal - I'm deleting prior comment to avoid the "discussion" trigger, you might want to do the same. Back to the issue, is this your merge sort function or are you calling some type of library function, and is it a pure merge sort or something like timsort? Could you try sorting 16 to 32 million integers, to get the time over a second or so?